# Transition is not smooth while filtering data

Tags: css, css-transitions

I have created a portfolio list in hexagon shape. But when I filter it, it's not happened smoothly. Please suggest what should I do for this?

I use css transition for it.

```
-webkit-transition: all 0.8s ease;
-moz-transition: all 0.8s ease;
-ms-transition: all 0.8s ease;
-o-transition: all 0.8s ease;
transition: all 0.8s ease;
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/s0ny00f3/)**

Comment: in place of ease use linear

Comment: already used but getting same effect.

Comment: What browser are you using? The difference is likely to be minimal but there will definitely be some difference in performance between browsers.

Comment: m using latest chrome version

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this will solve the problem and what you exactly expect for your smoothness, but this using `linear` instead of `ease` will definitely help to get things better

For more informations, here is some graph showing all the different timing for transition property

[image]

Comment: Can you explain PRECISELY what do you expect , maybe do you have an example on another site to show that will help, what is the problem with linear option?

Comment: To get the same smooth effect, you need to use their loibrary 'isotope' for jQuery, I'm not very familiar with angular, but you may consider using something more evolved than just CSS transition